# Can I use mod_rewrite redirect to different URLs?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

When I enter **http://www.example.com/index.php** to blowser
I can use rewriteRule to redirect to **http://www.example.com/web/index.php**

OK, now if I enter **http://www.example.com/test.php**
but the "test.php" file doesn't exist in web/ folder
actually, this file exist in /admin folder
so, can I redirect to **http://www.example.com/admin/test.php**?

use **http://www.example.com/xxx.php** redirect to different URLs?
following is my .htaccess but it cannot work...

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ admin/$1 [NC]

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# checks if requested file exists in /web/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/web%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]

# checks if requested file exists in /admin/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/admin%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L]
```